# How to debug the apt AbstractProcessor code generation?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, android-studio, annotation-processing

I'm trying to use apt and generate some code, so I've got a not working sample from [here](https://github.com/manolovn/apt-sample) imported it to Android Studio, made it work and placed it [here](https://bitbucket.org/nu-art-public/apt-sample) in case anyone else would want a working sample of APT on Android with Android Studio.

So Once I've got the project running and working I'm going to temper with it and stress its capabilities, and I would like to be able to debug my code and not only observe helplessly at the output.

So, how can I debug the code of the AbstractProcessor of APT, using Android Studio or Plain IntelliJ?

Answer (score 3):

Success... SO the solution is a combination of these two posts [one](http://www.pingtimeout.fr/2012/10/debugging-annotation-processor-in-every.html?showComment=1434914822211#c3042635104955475564) and [two](https://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2014/06/09/debug-an-annotation-processor-with-intellij-and-gradle/)...

So basically you add a **Remote** debug configuration (be sure the port is set to the same as the following lines), and add the following line to your **gradle.properties** file:

```
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
```

DONE! now you can debug your AnnotationProcessor!